# LibGDX Build Model error

Tags: gradle, libgdx, equinox

I am trying to create a LibGDX project using Gradle. I have already "created" the project using the Gradle setup app, but when I try to import it on Eclipse, I receive the following error:

org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1

I prompted me to see the error log, but (I know this is embarrassing) I can't locate the error log.

So I am stuck at the very last hurdle. One thing I may have done to cause the error was not downloading the Android component (I am not interested in creating apps, only desktop applications). I have unchecked the Android app box in the Gradle setup though. The "root folder" I created my project using the setup is in

C:[Name]\Programming\Game

Inside game were all my files like gradle, .gradle, core, desktop. The import box seemed to find it ok. It's just that build error that stops me (The progress bar barely went past %5 before giving me the error)

Answer (score 0):

To develop your application via Eclipse, you need to install the following pieces of software. You can find an in depth guide [HERE](http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/how-to-setup-your-libgdx-project/):

- **Java Development Kit 7+** (**JDK**) (6 will not work!): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- **Android SDK**:                                                                                                                                                  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html
- **Android Development Tools for Eclipse**:
  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (use this link as update site for eclipse)
- **Eclipse Integration Gradle**:
  http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly (for
  Eclipse 4.4) or http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (for
  Eclipse < 4.4)

Then you will need to **download the project generator** from here:
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html

Last but not least, you will need to **import** the project as **Gradle project** in Eclipse.
[image]

**See also:**

- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)
- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle